# Find a parametric equation of the given curve.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

The intersection of the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$ and the parabolic cylinder $y=x^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question?rq=1

Comment: n order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 1):

$z=x^2+y^2$ Substitute $y=x^2$

$z=x^2 + x^4$

$\begin{cases}z=t^4 + t^2\\y=t^2 \\x=t\end{cases}$